# Merging two md5 files in linux

Tags: linux, bash, merge, md5

**What I'm looking for is a way to merge the contents of two md5 files (let's call them `a.md5` and `b.md5`) in an automated fashion.**  Ideally I would like to do this from a bash script, but I am willing to explore alternatives.

I generate `a.md5` by doing:

```
cd a && find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum > ../a.md5
```

Where folder `a` has a number of files and directories within.
From another folder `b`, I similarly generate `b.md5`.
Here is a snippet of what the contents of the .md5 files will look like:

```
8f56e29ec16b2d59949c4a95b5607574  ./usr/share/man/man1/infocmp.1.gz
f245d527f4dd1fabab719b64414dccf7  ./usr/share/man/man1/clear.1.gz
c0ae88d29fc406c937c3f64511fa1ab0  ./usr/share/man/man1/modeline2fb.1
3b83017b7acd38a553c3132a0ccb1fd8  ./usr/share/man/man1/fbset.1
83530bf6b1a19ca69022536e7ca810b5  ./usr/share/man/man1/sqlite3.1
```

At a later time, folder `a` will have new files added to it (such as log files), and then be overwritten with folder `b`, so all unique files of folders `a` and `b` are present, and for all collisions, the file from `a` is replaced by the file from `b`.

Similarly, I would like to merge the contents of `a.md5` and `b.md5` so that in any collisions the `b.md5` value replaces the `a.md5` one for a particular file; however, since there are files added prior to the merge that I don't want in the results, I cannot simply recompute a new md5 file.

As a file note to give some context to the above needs, `a` and `b` are each the contents of embedded linux filesystems; the contents of `a` are programmed onto a clean file system, and the contents of `b` are unpacked into the filesystem at run-time.  The goal of the md5 is to verify the contents have been deployed without error, and ignore the files that are generated by various things at run-time.  I will be generating the md5 on my PC, and doing the `md5sum -c` on the embedded system.

As stated above, a bash script would be ideal, but I'm open to other suggestions as long as the process can be automated.

Comment: I'll have to do some checking (I'm still a padawan when it comes to more complex shell stuff); but the issue would be that the md5 sums will be theoretically different between duplicate files in a and b.

Comment: Actually, that seems to have worked rather nicely (thankfully, I was balking at the complexity of sed). I did: `cat b.md5 a.md5 | sort -k2 -u > c.md5`, this does exactly what I needed. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

One possilbe way: You can `sort -k2` both the lists and use `join -1 2 -2 2` to merge a.md5 and b.md5. Finally, you should remove the dupicate information for files present in both locations, `sed` should be able to do that.

Comment: Actually, you could use join to output in the format you want: `join -1 2 -2 2 a.md5 b.md5 -o '2.1,0'`, where the `-o` specifies the output format, where `2.1` uses the first field of the second file, and the `0` uses the "join field" (in this case the second field of either file).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
cat a.md5 b.md5|sort|uniq
```

Comment: Wound up tweaking this a bit to get it to work for me: `cat b.md5 a.md5 | sort -k2 -u > c.md5` this keeps all the entries from b only when a duplicate file name with a different md5sum.